# ambari-infra-solr rpm not available

Tags: java, hadoop, solr, ambari

I have build Ambari-2.7.5 by following this [url](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Installation+Guide+for+Ambari+2.7.5). The rpm which I get by building this is below:

```
ambari-admin-2.7.5.0-0.noarch.rpm
ambari-agent-2.7.5.0-0.x86_64.rpm
ambari-funtest-2.7.5.0-0.noarch.rpm
ambari-infra-2.7.5.0-0.noarch.rpm
ambari-infra-assembly-2.7.5.0-0.noarch.rpm
ambari-infra-manager-2.7.5.0-0.noarch.rpm
ambari-infra-manager-it-2.7.5.0-0.noarch.rpm
ambari-infra-solr-client-2.7.5.0-0.noarch.rpm
ambari-infra-solr-plugin-2.7.5.0-0.noarch.rpm
ambari-logsearch-2.7.5.0-0.noarch.rpm
ambari-logsearch-appender-2.7.5.0-0.noarch.rpm
ambari-logsearch-assembly-2.7.5.0-0.noarch.rpm
ambari-logsearch-config-api-2.7.5.0-0.noarch.rpm
ambari-logsearch-config-json-2.7.5.0-0.noarch.rpm
ambari-logsearch-config-local-2.7.5.0-0.noarch.rpm
ambari-logsearch-config-solr-2.7.5.0-0.noarch.rpm
ambari-logsearch-config-zookeeper-2.7.5.0-0.noarch.rpm
ambari-logsearch-it-2.7.5.0-0.noarch.rpm
ambari-logsearch-logfeeder-2.7.5.0-0.noarch.rpm
ambari-logsearch-logfeeder-container-registry-2.7.5.0-0.noarch.rpm
ambari-logsearch-logfeeder-plugin-api-2.7.5.0-0.noarch.rpm
ambari-logsearch-server-2.7.5.0-0.noarch.rpm
ambari-logsearch-web-2.7.5.0-0.noarch.rpm
ambari-metrics-2.7.5.0-0.noarch.rpm
ambari-metrics-assembly-2.7.5.0-0.noarch.rpm
ambari-metrics-collector-2.7.5.0-0.noarch.rpm
ambari-metrics-common-2.7.5.0-0.noarch.rpm
ambari-metrics-flume-sink-2.7.5.0-0.noarch.rpm
ambari-metrics-grafana-2.7.5.0-0.noarch.rpm
ambari-metrics-hadoop-sink-2.7.5.0-0.noarch.rpm
ambari-metrics-host-aggregator-2.7.5.0-0.noarch.rpm
ambari-metrics-host-monitoring-2.7.5.0-0.noarch.rpm
ambari-metrics-kafka-sink-2.7.5.0-0.noarch.rpm
ambari-metrics-storm-sink-2.7.5.0-0.noarch.rpm
ambari-metrics-storm-sink-legacy-2.7.5.0-0.noarch.rpm
ambari-project-2.7.5.0-0.noarch.rpm
ambari-server-2.7.5.0-0.x86_64.rpm
ambari-views-2.7.5.0-0.noarch.rpm
ambari-web-2.7.5.0-0.noarch.rpm
```

While setup of Ambari-2.7.5 I want ambari-infra-solr rpm to install infra solr service.
My question is that how to build ambari-infra-solr rpm?

Comment: Is that one not in list above?   I am working on same, very far into creating my own repos and custom stack...   I have reposync HDP 3.1.4 rpms and copy the dependencies I need into my own repo.  Sometimes I have to rename them to get the right version names.    I current have a 2.7.5 cluster online with nifi, zookeeper, Ambari Metrics, and hdfs....  In my repos I have my custom build 2.7.5 rpms, and all the public rpms for HDP & HDF..

Comment: @steven-dfheinz  In the list I have ambari-infra-solr-client and ambari-infra-solr-plugin and I want ambai-infra-solr. can you somehow get me the source code for ambari-infra-solr so that I can build my own rpm from there.

Comment: you could try here:  https://github.com/apache/ambari-infra

Comment: since its not a part of 2.7.5 you can also reposync 2.7.4 and copy the rpm you want (ambari-infra-solr-2.7.4.0-118.noarch.rpm). but maybe you can add that GitHub infra fileset into 2.75 so it does build as part of the entire ambari set?    Thats likely what they did for 2.7.4......   Did you also notice when you build 2.7.5 that the /var/lib/ambari-server/resources/stacks/ stops at HDP 2.6 ....  I need to spend some time today making my 2.7.5 have 3.0 & 3.1 so my DDP is fully compatible with HDP/HDF 3.x

Comment: Yes I also did notice that stack. It was strange. I also build my own stack for that. Did you get the ambari-ui issue while enabling NameNode HA you will get stuck in step 7. you have to make some changes in code to get pass through that.

Comment: im sure, its all a bit clunky if you ask me... currently working on trying to just get HDFS/Hadoop into my DDP stack, but im having a lot of problems trying to get HDP rpms to go in the versions I want...  im ending up with an even more clunky setup of /usr/hdp and usr/hdf with lots of conflicts in the symlinking....

Comment: did you build the rpm for infra?  I found a way to use rpmrebuild w/ hdp 3.1.4 files to reversion them to fit my stack.    It seems, in order to allow multi versions and upgrades, they key their component versions with the stack....  this gives me ability to repo sync last free version of HDP and HDF as the base of my stack, before I upgrade my own versions, other asf projects, and add third party components.....

Comment: hey @steven-dfheinz, yes I did build rpm for infra but now facing issue in ambari-metrics-collector start

Comment: @steven-dfheinz can you help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62265082/ambari-metrics-collector-service-not-starting

Answer (score 0):

@Rohit Sharma.   I just made some changes to the Ambari 2.7.5 source and wanted to collect all the rpms created.   Check out the output here:

```
[root@c7401 apache-ambari-2.7.5-src]# find -name *.rpm
./ambari-project/target/rpm/ambari-project/RPMS/noarch/ambari-project-2.7.5.0-0.noarch.rpm
./ambari-infra/ambari-infra-manager-it/target/rpm/ambari-infra-manager-it/RPMS/noarch/ambari-infra-manager-it-2.7.5.0-0.noarch.rpm
./ambari-infra/ambari-infra-assembly/target/rpm/ambari-infra-assembly/RPMS/noarch/ambari-infra-assembly-2.7.5.0-0.noarch.rpm
./ambari-infra/ambari-infra-solr-plugin/target/rpm/ambari-infra-solr-plugin/RPMS/noarch/ambari-infra-solr-plugin-2.7.5.0-0.noarch.rpm
./ambari-infra/ambari-infra-solr-client/target/rpm/ambari-infra-solr-client/RPMS/noarch/ambari-infra-solr-client-2.7.5.0-0.noarch.rpm
./ambari-infra/ambari-infra-manager/target/rpm/ambari-infra-manager/RPMS/noarch/ambari-infra-manager-2.7.5.0-0.noarch.rpm
./ambari-infra/target/rpm/ambari-infra/RPMS/noarch/ambari-infra-2.7.5.0-0.noarch.rpm
./ambari-logsearch/ambari-logsearch-config-solr/target/rpm/ambari-logsearch-config-solr/RPMS/noarch/ambari-logsearch-config-solr-2.7.5.0-0.noarch.rpm
./ambari-logsearch/ambari-logsearch-logfeeder/target/rpm/ambari-logsearch-logfeeder/RPMS/noarch/ambari-logsearch-logfeeder-2.7.5.0-0.noarch.rpm
./ambari-logsearch/ambari-logsearch-config-json/target/rpm/ambari-logsearch-config-json/RPMS/noarch/ambari-logsearch-config-json-2.7.5.0-0.noarch.rpm
./ambari-logsearch/ambari-logsearch-server/target/rpm/ambari-logsearch-server/RPMS/noarch/ambari-logsearch-server-2.7.5.0-0.noarch.rpm
./ambari-logsearch/ambari-logsearch-logfeeder-plugin-api/target/rpm/ambari-logsearch-logfeeder-plugin-api/RPMS/noarch/ambari-logsearch-logfeeder-plugin-api-2.7.5.0-0.noarch.rpm
./ambari-logsearch/ambari-logsearch-config-api/target/rpm/ambari-logsearch-config-api/RPMS/noarch/ambari-logsearch-config-api-2.7.5.0-0.noarch.rpm
./ambari-logsearch/ambari-logsearch-config-zookeeper/target/rpm/ambari-logsearch-config-zookeeper/RPMS/noarch/ambari-logsearch-config-zookeeper-2.7.5.0-0.noarch.rpm
./ambari-logsearch/ambari-logsearch-logfeeder-container-registry/target/rpm/ambari-logsearch-logfeeder-container-registry/RPMS/noarch/ambari-logsearch-logfeeder-container-registry-2.7.5.0-0.noarch.rpm
./ambari-logsearch/ambari-logsearch-assembly/target/rpm/ambari-logsearch-assembly/RPMS/noarch/ambari-logsearch-assembly-2.7.5.0-0.noarch.rpm
./ambari-logsearch/ambari-logsearch-config-local/target/rpm/ambari-logsearch-config-local/RPMS/noarch/ambari-logsearch-config-local-2.7.5.0-0.noarch.rpm
./ambari-logsearch/ambari-logsearch-web/target/rpm/ambari-logsearch-web/RPMS/noarch/ambari-logsearch-web-2.7.5.0-0.noarch.rpm
./ambari-logsearch/ambari-logsearch-appender/target/rpm/ambari-logsearch-appender/RPMS/noarch/ambari-logsearch-appender-2.7.5.0-0.noarch.rpm
./ambari-logsearch/ambari-logsearch-it/target/rpm/ambari-logsearch-it/RPMS/noarch/ambari-logsearch-it-2.7.5.0-0.noarch.rpm
./ambari-logsearch/target/rpm/ambari-logsearch/RPMS/noarch/ambari-logsearch-2.7.5.0-0.noarch.rpm
./ambari-agent/target/rpm/ambari-agent/RPMS/x86_64/ambari-agent-2.7.5.0-0.x86_64.rpm
./ambari-funtest/target/rpm/ambari-funtest/RPMS/noarch/ambari-funtest-2.7.5.0-0.noarch.rpm
./ambari-server/target/rpm/ambari-server/RPMS/x86_64/ambari-server-2.7.5.0-0.x86_64.rpm
./ambari-web/target/rpm/ambari-web/RPMS/noarch/ambari-web-2.7.5.0-0.noarch.rpm
./ambari-views/target/rpm/ambari-views/RPMS/noarch/ambari-views-2.7.5.0-0.noarch.rpm
./ambari-metrics/ambari-metrics-assembly/target/rpm/ambari-metrics-assembly/RPMS/noarch/ambari-metrics-assembly-2.7.5.0-0.noarch.rpm
./ambari-metrics/ambari-metrics-common/target/rpm/ambari-metrics-common/RPMS/noarch/ambari-metrics-common-2.7.5.0-0.noarch.rpm
./ambari-metrics/ambari-metrics-host-aggregator/target/rpm/ambari-metrics-host-aggregator/RPMS/noarch/ambari-metrics-host-aggregator-2.7.5.0-0.noarch.rpm
./ambari-metrics/ambari-metrics-grafana/target/rpm/ambari-metrics-grafana/RPMS/noarch/ambari-metrics-grafana-2.7.5.0-0.noarch.rpm
./ambari-metrics/ambari-metrics-timelineservice/target/rpm/ambari-metrics-collector/RPMS/noarch/ambari-metrics-collector-2.7.5.0-0.noarch.rpm
./ambari-metrics/ambari-metrics-hadoop-sink/target/rpm/ambari-metrics-hadoop-sink/RPMS/noarch/ambari-metrics-hadoop-sink-2.7.5.0-0.noarch.rpm
./ambari-metrics/ambari-metrics-flume-sink/target/rpm/ambari-metrics-flume-sink/RPMS/noarch/ambari-metrics-flume-sink-2.7.5.0-0.noarch.rpm
./ambari-metrics/ambari-metrics-storm-sink/target/rpm/ambari-metrics-storm-sink/RPMS/noarch/ambari-metrics-storm-sink-2.7.5.0-0.noarch.rpm
./ambari-metrics/ambari-metrics-kafka-sink/target/rpm/ambari-metrics-kafka-sink/RPMS/noarch/ambari-metrics-kafka-sink-2.7.5.0-0.noarch.rpm
./ambari-metrics/ambari-metrics-storm-sink-legacy/target/rpm/ambari-metrics-storm-sink-legacy/RPMS/noarch/ambari-metrics-storm-sink-legacy-2.7.5.0-0.noarch.rpm
./ambari-metrics/ambari-metrics-host-monitoring/target/rpm/ambari-metrics-host-monitoring/RPMS/noarch/ambari-metrics-host-monitoring-2.7.5.0-0.noarch.rpm
./ambari-metrics/target/rpm/ambari-metrics/RPMS/noarch/ambari-metrics-2.7.5.0-0.noarch.rpm
./ambari-admin/target/rpm/ambari-admin/RPMS/noarch/ambari-admin-2.7.5.0-0.noarch.rpm
./target/rpm/ambari/RPMS/noarch/ambari-2.7.5.0-0.noarch.rpm
```

I think you might already have them you just have to dig the rpm paths out from the entire build.

Comment: I am also searching rpm with the same command but i didn't get that from the Ambari but I had got the rpm from the link you provided. one question what did you change in the source code

Comment: just some touches of the node/npm/maven versions.   my build command is: mvn -B clean install rpm:rpm -DnewVersion=2.7.5.0.0 -DbuildNumber=5895e4ed6b30a2da8a90fee2403b6cab91d19972 -DskipTests -Dpython.ver="python >= 2.7"

Comment: I am also using the same command for build. I have also changed the version of node, npm still I didn't get that package. Don't know why but at last the github repo of ambari-infra works.

Comment: Hey @steven-dfheinz, Do you know how to get pretick in setup page of Ambari for services such as LOGSEARCH. I have searched that in stack but couldn't find any possible answer.

Comment: How are you delivering the services to ambari?   I am using a management pack to add 3.0 and 3.1 this also creates the stack in the stack select step.   You should be able to find something in /var/lib/ambari-server/resources/ that correlates to precheck on the services.   It could be something in log search itself too, I do know that service is different....

Comment: If you want to completely remove log search,  just remove all references.   I just did another install, and the pretick is related to "technical preview" , so maybe if you can find the reference to that,  you can adjust the source code....   also,   how about you meet me on the ASF Slack, #ambari channel....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215856/discussion-between-steven-dfheinz-and-rohit-sharma).