# Ambari-metrics-collector service not starting

Tags: java, hadoop, ambari

I have setup Ambari-2.7.5 with below services:

1. HDFS
2. YARN
3. MAPREDUCE2
4. HBASE
5. ZOOKEEPER
6. INFRA SOLR
7. AMBARI METRICS
8. ATLAS
9. KAFKA
10. KNOX
11. LOGSEARCH

All the services are in green state except Ambari Metrics. I have build ambari-metrics-collector rpm using [github.com/apache/ambari-metrics](https://github.com/apache/ambari-metrics). while starting ambari-metrics the process get stuck giving below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/HDP/3.0/services/AMBARI_METRICS/package/scripts/metrics_collector.py", line 90, in <module>
    AmsCollector().execute()
  File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/libraries/script/script.py", line 355, in execute
    self.execute_prefix_function(self.command_name, 'post', env)
  File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/libraries/script/script.py", line 386, in execute_prefix_function
    method(env)
  File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/libraries/script/script.py", line 428, in post_start
    raise Fail("Pid file {0} doesn't exist after starting of the component.".format(pid_file))
resource_management.core.exceptions.Fail: Pid file /var/run/ambari-metrics-collector//hbase-ams-master.pid doesn't exist after starting of the component.
```

[image: Ambari Setup]

Comment: I built my Ambari Metrics rpms from the same project as ambari 2.7.5.   If you followed the directions to build Ambari Metrics, you just have to dig out the right paths and get the rpms (5 total).    You can see mine here:  https://www.makeopensourcegreatagain.com/rpms/

Comment: what did you do to get HDP 3 stack into your cluster?

Comment: What step did you follow can you share? please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@RohitSharma You should be able to build the correct Ambari Metric RPMS during your ambari 2.7.5 build.

On the [Install Guide for Ambari 2.7.5](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Installation+Guide+for+Ambari+2.7.5) are these steps:

```
pushd ambari-metrics
mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=2.7.5.0.0
popd
```

Next on the [Ambari Development](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Ambari+Development) page, you should find the following details:

[image]

The rpms you need are:

```
ambari-metrics-2.7.5.0-0.noarch.rpm
ambari-metrics-collector-2.7.5.0-0.x86_64.rpm
ambari-metrics-grafana-2.7.5.0-0.x86_64.rpm
ambari-metrics-hadoop-sink-2.7.5.0-0.x86_64.rpm
ambari-metrics-monitor-2.7.5.0-0.x86_64.rpm
```